# Download a file using python from a link that redirects

Tags: python-2.7

I have a few thousand urls that I need to go to and download a file from there.

I have tried using `urllib` and requests and both of them seem to complete successfully but when I look at the downloaded file, it is always the same with an error message.

I am running `python 2.7` from a windows 10 computer.

I tried the following and get a file test4.pdf on my computer when the script completes.

```py
import requests

dls = "http://wbdocsservices.xxOrgNamexx.org/services?I4_SERVICE=FILE_URLS2&amp;RENDITION=Y&amp;I4_DOCID=090224b0828cd94a&amp;stream=Yes"

response = requests.get(dls)
with open("test4.pdf", "wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(response.content)
```

`test4.pdf` is not recognised and does not open. On renaming the file to `test4.txt`, I am able to open it. The contents of this file is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Securid Redirect Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://wbssocert.xxOrgNamexx.org/fed/secure/crxredirect.jsp" />
</head>
<body />
</html>
```

Also, I see that when I click on the link (in `Chrome` or `IE`) that I am trying to download, it open a pdf document but the address field says -

> http://wbescsprd3.xxOrgNamexx.org:9280/ACS/servlet/ACS?command=read&version=2.3&docbaseid=0224b0&basepath=%2Fwbpfiles26%2Fwbecmoksp%2Fdata%2Fwbecmoksp%2Fwbdocs_storage_25%2F000224b0&filepath=80%2F01%2F2e%2F62.pdf&objectid=090224b0828cd94a&cacheid=dggEAgA%3D%3DYi4BgA%3D%3D&format=pdftext&pagenum=0&signature=oWk4P5lnQ41G9e6L%2BeQIAmMrq%2BrkHDq5XsZDD2yZ7Gm60YkKuXWHhsbuuONqev4MFbGIB6C6GJiXefsK4RF8i7tBbfczFvDSiJTgBHB2YPZ0es%2BU%2BGCxeMmmYf67pI2mC36CawfqkifjTfE4otqfu%2BSY2TGxmQ1uIZrZOnQo4Is%3D&servername=Awbescsprd3_wbecmoksp&mode=1&timestamp=1562058840&length=9397463&mime_type=application%2Fpdf&parallel_streaming=true&encryption_mode=require&expire_delta=360

I used `urllib` and got exactly the same results as mentioned above.
Any help or pointers on how I can download the file.

Thanks a ton